# Cannot find source files error

Tags: asp.net

While configuring IIS and deploying my Web Application , I did something in Visual Studio while trying to deploy project. and all my code behind files dissapeared. I didn't delete them on purpose .

Now  I don't have any .cs and . config and .layout files in my folder which is

```
C:\Users\linklee\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\mykladr
```

it's a web application .Yesterday i just wanted to deploy and run my site in local network, but then something happened ( may be i pressed something or i don't know and my source file like default.aspx.cs dissapeared but default.aspx for example still exists and now i want them back .Anyone knows what is the problem ? Can i restore files from temporary .net folder?

Printscreen of solution explorer with missing files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeCHv.jpg

Comment: Did you publish the project to the same folder as the solution?

Comment: Never done it before, but if you publish the project to the same folder and tell it to delete all the files prior to publish, then you might have gotten yourself into a bit of a mess :|

Comment: did some thing, and publishing in the same folder, a huge gap

Comment: Thanks now i understand what the problem is. I suppose i will restore project from old version. There is not a brilliant way  but it's better than nothing..